# Navigation Drawer covers my toolbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, material-design

I am using this example of material design navigation drawer,the issue is,when i open my drawer,it covers my action bar too..and my drawer icon is not visible..this is the what i am getting..and following is my code..

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_body"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="info.androidhive.materialdesign.activity.FragmentDrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: If you follow the material design navigation drawer pattern, it actually should cover the action bar. https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: i want to make view like fiverr app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest to use a linear layout with vertical orientation as parent and then the first child is your toolbar and the second your drawer layout.

```
linearlayout vertical
  toolbar
  drawerlayout
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: post with xml so that it will help otheres too

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you have in `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` will be covered by Navigation drawer. See that you have your toolbar in `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`, so it is below navigation drawer. All you have to do is keep it out of `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`. These are all views, so design your layout in such a way that your toolbar is above `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` and its subviews.

However I should state that after Android 5.0 Lollipop, according to material guidelines, the navigation drawer is supposed to go over toolbar. But it is in no way necessary for you to do.

Here is an example layout
(However, understanding the theory part is necessary as you can create any type of layout after that)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/toolBarStyle"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
            class="com.buzzintown.consumer.drawer.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            android:layout_width="310dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            tools:layout="@layout/drawer_layout" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post as answer with xml so that it will helpful top others

Comment: @Lakhan I have added an example layout. See that the toolbar is outside DrawerLayout viewGrouo. So drawer will go not go over toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

This is example of latest navigation view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

   android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <!--content_main is my layout you can design your own-->
    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

 <!-- The navigation drawer with menu items defined in activity_main_drawer  -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Listview` instead of `fragment` it will make navigation drawer below Actionbar.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            style="@style/MyToolBarStyle.Base"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <!-- activity view -->
        <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <!-- navigation drawer -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/slider_dimen"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:divider="#000"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Modifying your code for the result you expect:

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

       android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

   <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="info.androidhive.materialdesign.activity.FragmentDrawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

   </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>


Your Welcome...
```