# Navigation Drawer Covers arrow android

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

I am working on an app where I am using the NavigationDrawerActivity.
When I tap on the hamburger icon, the navigation drawer slides in. But it covers the animation from hamburger to arrow.
Is there anyway I can use my NavigationDrawer below the actionbar instead of over the actionbar.

How I want is this:
[image: Arrow and animation is visible]

How I am getting is this:
[image: Drawer covers the animation]

Comment: If your are using toolbar, check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32007187/navigation-drawer-covers-my-toolbar

Comment: avoid to use navigation view

Comment: Please add your code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple. You just need to change activity_layout.xml

If you have created Activity with NavigationDrawer use see the following:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
...
>

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
 ...
 />
```

And You need to change it to

```
<RelativeLayout
... 
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
          android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    ...
    >

         <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
         ...
         />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/app_bar_layout"
    ... 
    >

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            ...
        />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If I do this, then the actionbar goes too up into the battery and network icons

Comment: add android:fitsSystemWindows="true" to root Relative layout

Comment: In additional: if you have in project v21/styles.xml  check <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item> and set needed color to <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>

Answer (score 0):

Try this !

```
 <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <!-- The ActionBar -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <!-- The main content view, you should replace this with your content -->

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textme"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    />
               <!-- The main content view -->


            </LinearLayout>


            <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                android:id="@+id/nvView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
                app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
                android:theme="@style/navbody"
                />

        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```